# Android Studio: emulator won't install

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am running Android Studio 3.2.1 on 32-bit Windows Vista. When it came to running a default tryout application and the emulator choosing window popped up I couldn't install am emulator. It asked me which version of Android and dimensions but then the window closes and the app doesn't run. Any ideas about what is going wrong here and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually figured out what went wrong. The emulator instances now show up when I run the application but then upon launching the app in the emulator I get the following error messages:

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Windows 7 or newer is required to run the Android Emulator.
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

So no, it's not possible to run the emulator on Windows Vista.

Answer (score -1):

[image]Try GenyMotion Android Emulator , it has a lot of features.

Comment: I tried downloading it but it's asking me € 99 per year. It's a bit pricey. Not sure why I couldn't get it onto my desktop for free.

Comment: Go to this link and download the personal Edition Joselin : https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/   (you need to create an account to Download the Personal Edition)